# Turn On GPS on rooted devices

Tags: android, gps

This question about turning on/off GPS programatically on android has been discussed many times, and the answer is always the same: You can't for security/privacy reasons. 
But is there any way for rooted devices to turn on gps with some edit in system settings..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a working solution fot rooted. See in one of my answers in profile. I cannot elaborate right now (in hospital). But currently you need root and busybox. I'm trying to make it working without busybox. Tested with 2.3.5  4.0.1 and 4.1.2

http://rapidshare.com/files/3977125468/GPSToggler-20130214.7z

Comment: I think the Busybox is not necessary. Updated: http://rapidshare.com/files/1458124346/GPSToggler-20130222.7z

Comment: File not found... please can you provide another link (maybe dropbox?)

Comment: You have to download it yourself from GIT   https://github.com/sms2000/GPSToggler

Comment: Hey OGP, how have you managed the GPS disclaimer message that shows when enabling network localization? It's possibile to remove or hide it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure I understand it well. What message? The one in the notification area? It's purpose is solely making the service important for Android. So it's restarted automatically as soon as possible after Android killed the application.

Comment: Go in settings > Localization and manually enable the network localization. This will show an activity that ask if you want to enable the network localization. Via netcat I've found a way for reopen this activity via adb: 
am start com.google.android.location/.ConfirmAlertActivity

If you programmatically use Secure.putString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED, "gps,network"); for enable the network localization this activity is showed asking to user for allowing network localization, until the user allow this, the network localization won't enabled.

Comment: You need not to open any activities if you gained the system level privileges. I hope the source code is self-explaining. Actually you need to build a small stub application which only turns GPS on and off according to some external commands (broadcast or so). Put the stub into /system/app or /system/sec-app (for KitKat) and reboot. To do it you need 'root' access (or custom ROM).

Comment: Thanks for your reply OGP, I saw your code and it actually enable only the GPS localization (no network based localization). In your code you do 'String newSet = String.format ("%s,%s", beforeEnable, LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);' and allow only GPS localization no Network. If you instead call Secure.putString(context.getContentResolver(), Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED, "gps,network"); your code will show up a notification from android about the allowing of the network localization. I want to remove this annoying message! Thanks

Comment: That's strange. The 'off' portion of the code returns the string which had been read from when enabling GPS. If it was 'network', the same will be reinstalled. And I see no message...

Comment: This popup will displayed only when ENABLING network localization (not disabling), you could try to enable it manually in settings.apk an see what happens. The same will happen if you execute it programmatically. No solutions found for now.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Turn ON/OFF GPS programmatically up-to Android 2.2(API 8)**

Here is the code I am using

```
public class GpsOnOff extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button onButton;
    Button offButton;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        onButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnON);
        offButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOFF);

        onButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        offButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if(v==onButton){

            //this will work upto 2.2 api only
            turnGPSOn();

            //this will work for all but it Navigate to 
                         GPS setting screen only 
            //not change settings automatically
            /*Intent in = new  Intent(android.provider.Settings
                         .ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS); 
            startActivity(in);*/


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "gps enabled", 1).show();
        }
        else if(v==offButton){
            turnGPSOff();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                           "gps disabled", 1).show();
        }

    }

    private void turnGPSOn(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure
           .getString(getContentResolver(),  
                Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(!provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is disabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", 
                        "com.android.settings.widget
                     .SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }

    private void turnGPSOff(){
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(
            getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure
              .LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
            final Intent poke = new Intent();
            poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", 
                   "com.android.settings.widget
              .SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
            poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
            poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
            sendBroadcast(poke);
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you need to add below two permissions to `manifest` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Either you can set target is 2.2 this will work fine or In above android versions >2.2, what you can do is just navigate user to the GPS settings screen in device.

Comment: actually i dont want user to navigate to settings screen I know its a bad idea.. but is there any possible way to do it.. with rooted device and some edit in system settings..